# Joining table into 4 columns

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, join

I've a problem to show 4 different columns from different table, for more detail, let see in the below :

Table personal (tbl_personal)

```
+---+-----+------------+
|ID |Name |Skill       |
+---+-----+------------+
| 1 | Nia | Accountant |
| 2 | Tia | Banking    |
| 3 | Ria | Technicall |
| 4 | Dia | Admin      |
+---+-----+------------+
```

Table master (tbl_master)

```
+---+---------+---------+
|ID |Employee1|Employee2|
+---+---------+---------+
| 1 | 1       | 2       |
| 2 | 2       | 1       |
| 3 | 3       | 4       |
+---+---------+---------+
```

I want to show into web page from tbl_master above in codeigniter like this :

```
+---+-------+-----------+-------+-----------+
|ID |Name 1 |Skill 1    |Name 2 |Skill 2    |
+---+-------+-----------+-------+-----------+
| 1 | Nia   | Accountant| Tia   | Banking   |
| 2 | Tia   | Banking   | Nia   | Accountant|
| 3 | Ria   | Technicall| Dia   | Admin     |
+---+---------+---------+-------+-----------+
```

Please advice if any suggestion for me to join from tbl_personal with tbl_master,

Thanks for your support...

Comment: have you tried any thing ? if yes then show us

Comment: What you want is called Pivoting Table or Transpose row to columns search here and you will find it. There are tons of examples.

Comment: i tried this    
$d['data_get'] = $this->db->query("select * from tbl_master right join tbl_personal on tbl_master.id_master=tbl_personal.id_master1 LIMIT ".$offset.",".$limit."");
but i'd problem just name 1 and skill 1 shown, i tried add id_master2 after that, i found an error.. - @knowledge....

Comment: @karisma you can reedit your question with code by clicking on edit button below your tags

Comment: @karisma have you tried my question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to join two time personal table. like below

```
select tp1.name name1,tp1.skill skill1,tp2.name name2,tp2.skill skill2 
from tbl_master tm
join tbl_personal tp1
on tm.Employee1 =tp1.ID
join tbl_personal tp2
on tm.Employee2 =tp2.ID
```

Comment: what if they have more than 4 skills

Comment: there is a employee in both column and i need to just joi it with employee table

Comment: i'm sorry, i've tried, but still there's an error like this                                                   

"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'on 
tm.Employee1 =tp1.ID join tbl_personal on tp2 on tm.Employee2 =tp2.ID' at line 4
select tp1.name name1,tp1.skill skill1,tp2.name name2,tp2.skill skill2 from tbl_master tm join tbl_personal on tp1
on tm.Employee1 =tp1.ID join tbl_personal on tp2 on tm.Employee2 =tp2.ID
Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\kpu\system\database\DB_driver.php"

Comment: @karisma check now i have a mistake

Comment: @knowledge....it work's, thanks! but i have another problem, i can't show another field coloumn from tbl_master, could you help me again? thanks before

Comment: just add or ask new question i will help

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use 2 joins for this. Also you have to be careful in selecting columns after joining

```
SELECT tp1.name as Name1, tp1.Skill as Skill1,tp2.name as Name2, tp2.Skill as Skill2
FROM tbl_master tm1
JOIN tbl_personal tp1 on tp1.id = tm1.Employee1
JOIN tbl_personal tp2 on tp2.id = tm1.Employee2
```

This should be the output for this query.

[image]

Just add `ID` column in select query.